# Should I be worried about a surge protector near my pillow

Tags: safety, surge-protection, emf

I have just realized how close my surge protector appears to be to my pillow. It is about 20-30cm away. Should I be worried about any EMF/radiation/something else? The surge protector itself is new and wiring is fine.

[image]

Comment: Are you worried about your walls being filled with electrical wiring? Or your phone emitting electromagnetic radiation while you use it? This is not something to worry about. The only issue that might be vaguely worrying is heat. Is it overheating because lots of things are plugged into it and it's covered with blankets, for example?

Comment: More like my brain spending good 8 hours a day near that thing

Comment: Electromagnetic 'radiation' is the non-ionizing type of radiation, not to be confused with 'radioactive' ionizing radiation (which would be potentially harmful). It takes a very high effective radiated power for EMF to cause RF burns, much higher power than a consumer product would use. I'd be more concerned about heat or exposed wiring, neither of which is evident in the photo. EM field strength falls off very rapidly with distance, so if it really makes you worry so much you can't sleep, just move it to another location or move your bed a few inches back from the wall.

Comment: Don't drool onto it while you sleep. You might get a shock.

Comment: Where do you live? Do you have a lot of lightning strikes?

Comment: The risk would be a fire. If there is any risk. You can move it farther from your bed. Make sure your room has a smoke detector. And maybe if you are really paranoid, make sure the surge suppressor is mounted on a non-flammable surface (such as a plaster wall or masonry or tile floor).

Answer (score 2):

It is very doubtful that you are in danger as a result of electromagnetic radiation. The primary hazard from a surge suppressor would be that it may conduct large currents in a lightning strike, possibly even blowing up, and that it may become very hot in the case of certain types of internal failures. It could even start a house fire. Moving it farther away from your bed couldn't hurt. If possible, mount it on a surface with at least some amount of fire resistance, such as plaster, drywall, or on a floor made of masonry or tile. Do not allow it to be covered with flammable materials or anything that might prevent it from dissipating heat effectively (such as a blanket or clothing).

It would be a good idea to make sure the suppressor has the correct safety agency rating applicable for where you live. That would be the UL in the USA. Properly designed surge suppressors should have some type of thermal disconnect or thermal fuse to make sure that they do not continue to operate when they get too hot.

But shoddy devices, or old ones may be missing this safety feature.

It is a good idea to have a smoke detector in every bedroom, too.

Answer (score 1):

The industry that addresses the effects that you are concerned about is called "Building Biology" There are hundreds of certified experts in the US in this area.

Their reference standard for non-ionizing radiation limits is;
[European Academy of Environmental Medicine Recommendations](https://www.mainecoalitiontostopsmartmeters.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/European-EUROPAEM-EMF-Guideline-2016-for-the-prevention-diagnosis-and-treatment-of-EMF-related-health-problems-and-illnesses.pdf)

If you advance to page 18 or so, you will see the field limits.
Depending upon frequency range, these my be Electric field and Magnetic field strengths, or it may be electromagnetic field strength.

You will need to purchase a field measurement instrument so that you can compare your situation with the Recommendations.

I suspect that you will need a Magnetic field measurement device, i.e. magnetometer.
Sometimes this is called an "AC Gauss meter".

Here is an online vendor who sells them.

I am in NO WAY affiliated with this company.

[LessEMF.com](http://lessemf.com/gauss.html)

For what it is worth, I personally take the European recommendations seriously.

Hope this helps !